# How do I remove a stuck sink soap dispenser?

Tags: plumbing, sink, soap-dispenser

[image: soap dispenser stuck piece]

I have a Blanco 440045 Alta soap dispenser that is broken. I want to 
remove it from my sink.

Unfortunately the piece highlighted in the image is stuck due to years of moisture and cannot easily be unscrewed. It seems impossible to remove the dispenser unless this piece is unscrewed or I cut through the main body piece of the dispenser.

1. What is the name of this piece?
2. Is there a tool I can use to unscrew this? Unfortunately it is completely round so I don't think a basin or socket wrench will work.
3. Would a hack saw or oscillating tool be able to cut through the threaded main body piece (which should allow me to remove the dispenser)?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Both methods below have merit I have used a dremel tool to cut the nut as jack suggests, I have also used a hacksaw wrapped with tape to cut a pipe in tight spaces. Both ways work so you have some good options to try.++

Answer (score 2):

I would use pipe pliers and if they fail then I would look to cut the threaded portion with a saw of some type.

In the past I have cut similar items in constricted areas by just using a hacksaw blade wrapped in a cloth to protect the fingers - slow slow progress but got there...

Answer (score 2):

If you can't loosen that collar with a pair of pliers, I'd try cutting a slit in that collar straight up and down all the way into the threads. Then put a screwdriver, slotted, into the slot and twist it to spread the collar and break the thread grab and twist the collar off